# Keep Mapbox Current Location Fixed on Pinch to Zoom in Android

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

Zooming with Pinch in Mapbox Keeps Changing the center , how to achieve the same result as zooming with double-tap + scrolling Finger with Pinch too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is to detect Zooming event and then Disable Scrolling till Zomming Ends , this works well in GoogleMaps but not properly in MapBox as the Scrolling wont get disabled (even when set to false programmatically) while zooming .
Another Way is to Add a Marker at the center of the Map the moment Zooming Starts and Removing it when it ends and show your own Marker (Probably an Image centered over the map )